# php conventions in conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, conventions, conditional-statements

I have system, that using keywords for some data

There are normal keywords and meta keywords - To:all, Tomember: and Togroup:

and I have following condition to check meta keywords:

```
if ((strpos($kwd, 'To:all') === 0) ||
    (strpos($kwd, 'Tomember:') === 0) ||
    (strpos($kwd, 'Togroup:') === 0))
{
    /* ... */
}
```

I think this way of identifying meta keywords is incorrect.

One more incorrect way is like this:

```
if ((strpos($kwd, 'To:all') !== FALSE) ||
    (strpos($kwd, 'Tomember:') !== FALSE) ||
    (strpos($kwd, 'Togroup:') !== FALSE))
{
    /* ... */
}
```

And in my opinion the correct way is:

```
if ((substr($kwd,0,6) == 'To:all') ||
    (substr($kwd,0,9) == 'Tomember:') ||
    (substr($kwd,0,8) == 'Togroup:'))
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the solutions you propose, the second is wrong because it will return true even if the meta-keywords do not appear in the beginning of `$kwd`. The other two work correctly.

An even better way would be:

```
function str_starts_with($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) == $needle;
}

if (str_starts_with($kwd, 'To:all') ||
    str_starts_with($kwd, 'Tomember:') ||
    str_starts_with($kwd, 'Togroup:'))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `strncmp($needle, $haystack, strlen($needle)) === 0`. According to some comments in the manual its about 20% faster.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Thanks for pointing that out. But let's not lose the forest for the trees here: we don't know if it will make a difference for the problem at hand (probably not) and, more significantly, we don't know how "a guy on the internet" benchmarked.

Comment: You already got +1 from me, because your answer is simply right ;) I just didnt want to create a separate answer for this little addition. However, I tested it myself (I used `substr()` this way before too) and its true. And it makes sense: Instead of creating a string from a longer one and then compare it against a third one it, it just compares two substrings (propably using Cs internal `strncmp()` function).

Answer (score 1):

```
strpos($kwd, 'To:all') === 0
```

will check if the `$kwd` string **begins** with `To:all` -- it'll check if the position of `To:all` in `$kwd` is 0.

```
strpos($kwd, 'To:all') !== FALSE
```

will check if the `$kwd` string **contains** `To:all` -- no matter at which position.

```
substr($kwd,0,6) == 'To:all'
```

whill check if the first 6 characters of `$kwd` are `To:all` -- which is equivalent to the first solution.

If you want to test the *begins with* case, you'll use the first or third solution.

Personnaly, I'd go with the strpos-based : I find it easier to read/understand ; but it's mainly a matter of personnal preferences.

If you want to test the *contains* case, you'll need to use the second solution.

Comment: Yes, I want to check _begins with_ case, and I want to gather some statistics - for me third case is more readable